# Trigger click function on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which is activated on click:

```
$('.results .view-rooms').click(function(){   }
```

Is there anyway I can trigger this function on document load?

Comment: `document ready` or `window load` you mixed them... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
    $(".results .view-rooms").click(); // click the element
})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.results .view-rooms').click()
```

You can put it in DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('.results .view-rooms').click()
});
```

Or `window load`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.results .view-rooms').click();
});
```

Note that there is no such event `document load`.
We have `DOM ready` or `window load`

Comment: I know what DOM is lol, I was just playfully pointing out that $(document).ready() exists

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt. `$(document).ready(fn)` is exactly the same as `$(fn)`, the second is an alias to the first.

Comment: hmm.. interesting - I actually didn't know that. Though it makes sense.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt. You might want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10753306/601179) if that was new to you. Disclaimer, it's my question and answer there.

Comment: well enjoy your +rep for teaching me something new (and pretty interesting, too)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.results .view-rooms').click(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you're already using jQuery to bind the event handler, and assuming that code is already in a position where the entire DOM has been constructed, you can just chain the call to `.click()` to then trigger that event handler:

```
$('.results .view-rooms')
                        .click(function(){...}) //binds the event handler
                        .click(); // triggers the event handler
```

Comment: +1 for the chain, I'm not sure he can use it in this case, But teaching the op the chainablility of jQuery is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Put the  code inside

```
$(function(){ // code here  });
```

like:

```
$(function(){ 
   $(".results .view-rooms").click(); 
});
```

or

```
$(function(){ 
   $(".results .view-rooms").trigger('click'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $('.results .view-rooms').click(function(){ 

    }

    $(".results .view-rooms").trigger('click');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:

html form:

```
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com" method="get">
  <button id="watchButton"></button>
</form>
```

End Jquery:

```
<script>
   $('document').ready(function() {
     $('#watchButton').click();
   });
</script>
```

JQuery Version:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
```