# JQuery masterpage issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have coder slider on a page.  It works fine on an *.aspx without a master page.   However when I used it on an *.aspx page that used a masterpage, it didn't work.  I solved it purely by chance when I found this;

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/manual-coda-slider-not-plugin-jquery-issueerrors

and changed  $(document).ready(function ()  to  $(document).ready(function ($).  Does anyone know why this would make a difference between a page that doesn't use a masterpage and a page that does?

The console error was - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'codaSlider'

If anyone can enlighten me, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.ready(function($){})` avoids conflict on the existing library that you might have in your system so the dollar sign (which is for jquery) is added rather than the simple `function()` without the parameter to avoid conflict. In your case it is most likely the WordPress Coda-Slider that conflicts with your jquery library.

See this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461478/what-is-the-difference-between-jqueryfunction-and-function) which basically in the same line as your question
and the Coda specific link [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/coda-slider-20-and-noconflict).